# Accessing App from global namespace

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I need to be able to debug an app I created using ember-cli (so it's using ES6 modules).

How can I access the App from the console of Chrome Developer Tools?

I'd like to be able to call commands like this:

`App.__container__.lookup('controller:index').get('students')`

Comment: [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) Makes your application's objects available in the console as the $E variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel free to do that, the app's name is shown in the `index.html` page located in the app directory.

```
 window.ExampleApp = require('example-app/app')...
```

In this case the app's name is ExampleApp

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed it because when I generated the app I called it `ember-cli-test`, so I thought that `window.EmberCliTest` was something related to the test environment...